# Getting error in creating new django program

Tags: python, django

this is the error i am getting. i have even dine reinstalling python but it's showing me this only.

i am actually trying to create new django program and this happend out of the blue

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\Aadil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Aadil\AppData\Local\Programs\Py thon\Python39\Scripts\django-admin.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: is the space in Python in your second file path a typo from you or does that match with your error?

Comment: no its just the typo error